# How does OSPF know the cost of the interfaces between the router and the destination network?

Tags: ospf

So OSPF calculates and adds the best route to its routing table. The best route is the one with the smallest metric - cost.

However, how does an OSPF enabled router know the cost of the interfaces that are between it and some destination?

[image]
In this case, how would R1 know what cost do routers R2 and R3 have associated with their interfaces?

I thought, at first, that its because of the Shortest Path First algorithm that it uses to calculate the routes based on the received LSA's, however, then why is there a "metric" field in a LSU message? Can someone give me some clarity on this? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LSAs exchanged by OSPF neighbors include a *metric* field that describes the *cost* or *distance*.

Each link cost is calculated by dividing a reference bandwidth like 200 Gbit/s (the default is 100 Mbit/s) by the interface link speed. The path cost is the sum of all used link costs.